# Understanding nmap output / author explanation ...(Scapy)

Tags: firewalls, ports, nmap

I just read this example and explanation (below) in the OReilly book *Security Power Tools* (2007) in section 6.3 that is written by the creator of Scapy, Philippe Biondi.  I think the example is very interesting, but I don't understand what it is saying.  Can someone clarify this goldmine of info he is referring to?

```
Here is another example of a tool interpreting a situation:
#nmap 192.168.9.3
Interesting ports on 192.168.9.3:
PORT STATE SERVICE
22/tcp filtered ssh
```

"Nmap says that the port is filtered, but this answer has been triggered by a host
unreachable ICMP error sent by the last router. In this context, the ICMP message
has been interpreted as The packet has been blocked on its way to the target, while it
should have been interpreted as The packet was to be delivered, but the target was not
reachable. This situation typically occurs when a port is allowed to pass on a whole
IP network block while not all IP addresses are used. This is a gold mine of information
when you want to set up a backdoor, but if you trust your tool, not only will
you miss the gold, but you’ll also lose the whole mine because Nmap makes you
wrongly assume no backdoor can be implanted there."
 *Security Power Tools* (2007)

Comment: You can use the `--reason` option to see what kind of response Nmap saw which resulted in the "filtered" status (or any other status). Or use the XML output, which always includes this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can take a swing at this, but I'm essentially guessing at the motivations of the author, the only person that can definitively answer this.

What he appears to be saying is, in the case above the filtered result might make you believe that a firewall rule is in place blocking access to port 22/TCP on 192.168.9.3 as such you might not think it possible to use that host and port for your own services (assuming you're the attacker here), but in reality access to that host isn't blocked, the IP address just isn't assigned.

It's true to say that to get the best out of tools like nmap, you need to understand what they're telling you.  "filtered" for TCP services really means "I didn't get a response".  Now if you're only checking hosts that have responded to some kind of pinging behaviour (the default with nmap) then that answer probably makes sense, as the host is present (it responded to ping) but it doesn't respond on that port (thus the filtered result).

In his example above I'd guess that the scan was run with -PN or similar so that nmap would scan hosts even with no response to ping.  In those circumstances "filtered" means "I got nothing back, that host may or may not actually be there"